# ArcGIS Pro Join works one way but not the other

Tags: sql, join, gis, arcgis, esri

To make this map I added a Building field to the feature layer. I also made a standalone table by using a SQL Query. For some reason when I try to join the two tables together I can join the feature layer on the query layer but not the other way around. Help would be much appreciated.

**These are all the fields and data types in the feature layer table:**

[image]

**These are some of the fields and data types in the data layer table:**

[image]

**Join on the Standalone table:**

[image]

**Join on feature layer table:**

[image]

All  values are showing when there is clearly values in the standalone table.

Thanks

I have tried relating the tables to be one to one relationship. I have made sure the data types are the same. None of the values have any unexpected spaces.